# how to allow using only specific usb flash drive in windows

Tags: windows, usb, usb-flash-drive, usb-storage, c++

The company I work for sells devices that run Windows 10/11, I need the device only use our company's usb flash drive, the total requirements are:

1. When other U disk is inserted, it should not be idendified by windows, nor show the disk. but for our U disk, it should work fine, can access and read/write.
2. We need mark one usb flash drive as special, for example change the vendor or write some special data to a special sector
3. When a user loses the U disk, we can send him/her a new one(already marked), the new one should work fine.

I did some research and by configuring Group Policy I can allow only specific USB devices to be accessed through Windows, but it requires the device ID, so this doesn't satisfy the third requirement above. Alternatively, there is a Qt(c++) application running in the device, we can recognize the marked U disk and get the device ID, then write to the group policy.

Does anyone has better idea? How to program Group Policy, c++ or power shell?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [USBDLM](https://www.uwe-sieber.de/usbdlm_e.html).  I am not associated with it but I use it to give drives with particular labels a particular letter.  It has many options, and I have only scratched the surface.

It's installed as a service.  Using the options I know, you can do this

1. Give your USB a unique label
2. Set up a Rule to pair this label with a desired drive letter (say Y)
3. Set up a Rule to pair all other labels to a different drive letter (say X)
4. Prohibit drive letter X from mounting.

There may well be more efficient ways of doing it.

> USBDLM is a Windows service that gives control over Windows' drive letter assignment for USB drives. Running as service makes it independent of the logged on user's privileges, so there is no need to give the users the privilege to change drive letters.
> It automatically solves conflicts between USB drives and network or subst drives of the currently logged on user.
> Furthermore you can define new default letters for USB drives and much more.
> It works on Windows XP to Windows 11 and Server 2003 to 2022.

It is free for personal use, and bulk licensing is cheap.